# The honest human heart or The honest human's heart?

Tags: possessives

Which form is correct?

"This is how the honest human heart look" or "This is how the honest human's heart look", and why?

Comment: The difference is whether _honest_ refers to the person or their heart. But it could be both: an honest person has an honest heart (but this is metaphoric). So the first sentence is synecdoche for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that "look" should be "looks" in both cases, neither form is more correct than the other. I prefer the former just because the possessive is unnecessary.